# When I add slashes I get numbers added to the record

Tags: cobol

```
01 EMPLOYEE-RECORD1.
       ...
       05  EMPLOYEEDOB1.
           10  MONTH1    PIC 99.
 *> here   10  FILLER   PIC X(1) VALUE "/".
           10  DAY11     PIC 99.
 *> here   10  FILLER   PIC X(1) VALUE "/".
           10  YEARS1   PIC 9(4).
 *> here
          05 EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY1 PIC ZZ,ZZZV99.
       ...
```

There is more to the program and I will provide the code if necessary. In short my program takes input from a file and then loads it into a temp record. Then I copy the data from the temp record into the record for the output file and it writes it to the output file. When it writes it I lose the pay data and it adds numbers for the DOB instead of slashes. Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
   program-id. Program1 as "NAME403.Program1".

   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT EMPFILE
              ASSIGN TO "C:\COBOLClass\DataFiles\NAME402.TXT"
              ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT NEWEMPFILE
               ASSIGN TO "C:\COBOLClass\DataFiles\NAME403.TXT"
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

   data division.

   FILE SECTION.
   FD EMPFILE.
   01 EMPLOYEE-RECORD.
       05 EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS.
           10 BLDGNUMB-AND-STREET  PIC X(10).
           10 CITY PIC X(10).
           10 STATE PIC X(10).
           10 ZIPCODE PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEENUMB PIC 9(6).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05  EMPLOYEEDOB.
            10  MONTH    PIC 99.
            10  DAY1     PIC 99.
            10  YEARS   PIC 9(4).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_FNAME   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_MNAME   PIC X(2).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_LNAME   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY PIC ZZ,ZZZ.99.

   FD NEWEMPFILE.

   01 EMPLOYEE-RECORD1.
       05 EMPLOYEENUMB1 PIC 9(6).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_FNAME1   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_MNAME1   PIC X(2).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_LNAME1   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05  EMPLOYEEDOB1.
           10  MONTH1    PIC 99.
            10  FILLER   PIC X VALUE "/".
            10  DAY11     PIC 99.
            10  FILLER   PIC X VALUE "/".
            10  YEARS1   PIC 9(4).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY1 PIC ZZ,ZZZ.99.
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS1.
           10 BLDGNUMB-AND-STREET1  PIC X(10).
           10 CITY1 PIC X(10).
           10 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
           10 STATE1 PIC X(10).
           10 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
           10 ZIPCODE1 PIC X(10).
           10 FILLER   PIC X(166) VALUE  "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------".




       05 EMPLOYEE_LNAME   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY PIC ZZ,ZZZ.99.

   FD NEWEMPFILE.

   01 EMPLOYEE-RECORD1.
       05 EMPLOYEENUMB1 PIC 9(6).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_FNAME1   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_MNAME1   PIC X(2).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_LNAME1   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05  EMPLOYEEDOB1.
           10  MONTH1    PIC 99.
            10  FILLER   PIC X VALUE "/".
            10  DAY11     PIC 99.
            10  FILLER   PIC X VALUE "/".
            10  YEARS1   PIC 9(4).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY1 PIC ZZ,ZZZ.99.
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS1.
           10 BLDGNUMB-AND-STREET1  PIC X(10).
           10 CITY1 PIC X(10).
           10 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
           10 STATE1 PIC X(10).
           10 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
           10 ZIPCODE1 PIC X(10).
           10 FILLER   PIC X(166) VALUE  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------".




   working-storage section.
   01 EMPLOYEE-RECORD-TEMP.
      05 EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS-TEMP.
           10 BLDGNUMB-AND-STREET-TEMP  PIC X(10).
           10 CITY-TEMP PIC X(10).
           10 STATE-TEMP PIC X(10).
           10 ZIPCODE-TEMP PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEENUMB-TEMP PIC 9(6).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05  EMPLOYEEDOB-TEMP.
            10  MONTH-TEMP   PIC 99.
            10  DAY1-TEMP     PIC 99.
            10  YEARS-TEMP   PIC 9(4).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_FNAME-TEMP   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_MNAME-TEMP   PIC X(2).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_LNAME-TEMP   PIC X(10).
       05 FILLER   PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
       05 EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY-TEMP PIC ZZ,ZZZ.99.

        01 SWITCHES.
           05 CUSTMAST-EOF-SWITCH  PIC X   VALUE "N".
       02 COUNTER PIC 9 VALUE 1.
   procedure division.

     000-STARTPROGRAM.
           open input EMPFILE
                output NEWEMPFILE.

           PERFORM 100-GET-INFROMATION
               UNTIL CUSTMAST-EOF-SWITCH="Y".
               display "END OF SESSION.".
               stop run.

     100-GET-INFROMATION.

     read EMPFILE into EMPLOYEE-RECORD-TEMP
     at END 

     MOVE EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS-TEMP TO EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS1.
     MOVE BLDGNUMB-AND-STREET-TEMP TO BLDGNUMB-AND-STREET1.
     MOVE CITY-TEMP TO CITY1.
     MOVE STATE-TEMP TO STATE1.
     MOVE ZIPCODE-TEMP TO ZIPCODE1.
     MOVE EMPLOYEENUMB-TEMP TO EMPLOYEENUMB1.

     MOVE MONTH-TEMP TO MONTH1.
     MOVE DAY1-TEMP TO DAY11.
     MOVE YEARS-TEMP TO YEARS1.
     MOVE EMPLOYEE_FNAME-TEMP TO EMPLOYEE_FNAME1.
     MOVE EMPLOYEE_MNAME-TEMP TO EMPLOYEE_MNAME1.
     move EMPLOYEE_LNAME-TEMP TO EMPLOYEE_LNAME1. 
     move EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY-TEMP to EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY1.

     WRITE EMPLOYEE-RECORD1.
     if COUNTER=5
     close EMPFILE
     close NEWEMPFILE
     move "Y" to CUSTMAST-EOF-SWITCH
     ELSE ADD 1 to COUNTER.
```

Comment: Your PICture for EMPLOYEE_YEARLYPAY1 is wrong, it should be ZZ,ZZZ.99 (a full-stop/period actual decimal-point replacing the V implied decimal-point). The VALUE statement will not "persist" if you MOVE data to the group item. If you MOVE a 9(8) to the group item, it will just do an alphammeric MOVE, giving you eight characters and two trailing blanks (padding). Individual MOVEs or define with the "/" editing symbol.

Comment: @BillWoodger Thank for that tipe, the pay is displaying correctly now. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual `MOVE` or `READ ... INTO` are missing but I assume you (directly or indirectly) move a `PIC 9(06)` item to `EMPLOYEEDOB1` which is a different format actual a `PIC X(08)`.

As long as the question isn't improved (by showing both the data definition and the statement for the "copy") I say the answer to "What am I doing wrong?" is: You use the wrong definition for EMPLOYEEDOB1 and/or "copy" the data in falsely.

The target field definition must either match the original data or be changed to an edited field like `PIC 99/99/99` (where the `/` are added automatically in the `DISPLAY`/`WRITE` you do with it) - in the later case: be aware that you cannot do any arithmetic with an edited field.

Alternative: `MOVE` all three parts of the date-of-birth (DOB) on their own and you can keep your definition (only useful if you want to do anything with the three parts afterwards).